# mod-pagespeed and tree menu behaviour

Tags: joomla, mod-pagespeed

We're having a very peculiar problem with a site that is using mod-pagespeed. Here's the link in question - 
http://www.microsemi.com/applications/

If you try to expand one of the sections by clicking on the '+' sign you need to click twice to open.

However if you disable pagespeed using http://www.microsemi.com/applications/?ModPagespeed=off
The link works correctly.

What is the best way to debug this ? Is is possible to selectively disable javascripts from being processed by mod-pagespeed ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start first of all with looking at the errors that are thrown up on the page in chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tips is not defined www.microsemi.com:43
Failed to load resource http://www.microsemi.com/media/system/js/mootools-more.js.pagespeed.ce.BqakF5Rbjl.js
```

These are presumably related as the errors vanish on the second link without page-speed. I'd assume the second one must be the reason why two clicks is needed - for some reason there is a javascript file missing using mod_pagespeed - also presumably containing jQuery UI.

I should probably add that it says [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/mod-pagespeed-settings/#.UMh3voMQFMk) mod-pagespeed only seems to be of use for badly written sites. Joomla is well written so as long as you have well functioning extensions there should be negligible difference on your site!